# {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

I am at the end where I am doing `$ aws lambda invoke --function-name CreateTableAddRecordsAndRead output.txt`

I was getting an error that pymysql could not be found, so I saw a tutorial on pip installing the package to your zip file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Now I have the following folder structure

```
$ ls aws_mysql_tutorial
__init__.py  app.py  output.txt  package/
```

I have zipped this folder up and updated the code for this lambda

```
$ aws lambda update-function-code --function-name CreateTableAddRecordsAndRead --zip-file "fileb://aws_mysql_tutorial.zip"
```

Now I get a new error message

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
```

This confuses me because the code I zipped up has an init file and a python file named app.py. Now that it has the pymysql package I no longer get the old error.

The app.py is the same as shown on the middle of tutorial page

```
import sys
import logging
import pymysql

#rds settings
rds_host  = "rds-instance-endpoint"
name = "admin"
password = "blah"
db_name = "ExampleDB"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")

def handler(event, context):
    """
    This function fetches content from MySQL RDS instance
    """

    item_count = 0

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("create table Employee ( EmpID  int NOT NULL, Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (EmpID))")
        cur.execute('insert into Employee (EmpID, Name) values(1, "Joe")')
        cur.execute('insert into Employee (EmpID, Name) values(2, "Bob")')
        cur.execute('insert into Employee (EmpID, Name) values(3, "Mary")')
        conn.commit()
        cur.execute("select * from Employee")
        for row in cur:
            item_count += 1
            logger.info(row)
            #print(row)
    conn.commit()

    return "Added %d items from RDS MySQL table" %(item_count)
```

The init file is empty.

Comment: Hi cody. Please try to refrain from adding thanks, appreciations, greetings and other fluff. We prefer technical writing here. Meta references are available on request.

Comment: I sometimes offer the following feedback, to cover what editors find! _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._